# Use custom git command with buildnumber-maven-plugin

Tags: git, maven, buildnumber-maven-plugin, rpm-maven-plugin

I'm currently working on automating the build process (more or less) using `maven`.
I need to create an rpm but in order to do so, I need to retrieve the latest version. As part of the convention, we're using `GIT`'s tags to store the version of the system on the master branch.
Unfortunately, buildNumber-maven-plugin is using `git show` instead of `git describe` and I can't find a suitable configuration for it to work.
How should I configure this thing ?

Comment: Are you forced to use this plugin? Because we use *git-commit-id-plugin* and it works like a charm. It's very easy to configure.

Comment: @musiKk does the plugin exports a `${buildNumber}` variable like the buildnumber-maven-plugin? The doc is not very informative...

Comment: Hm, I find the [documentation](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) pretty extensive. It supports a number of variables that can be exported to a properties file or applied to other files via Maven's filtering.

Comment: @musiKk But then I'll need to read from that properties file. I'd rather use them in the pom just like the `buildNumber` in `buildnumber-maven-plugin`

Comment: Ah, I think I didn't really get your problem so far. I don't think what you want is possible. In any case I didn't want to convince you. It's an alternative I'm happy with but it doesn't seem to work for you. :)

Comment: actually that plugin seems like a good solution... I just need it to export the version extracted from `git describe` by this plugin. Buildnumber-maven-plugin provides just that, but uses `git show` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @musiKk 's suggestion, I used `git-commit-id-plugin`. I had several problems at first because I didn't configure it properly.
Though the plugin is not mature enough, it's getting the job done.